# Optimize the Kernel parameters of RBF kernel for GPR in scikit-learn using internally supported optimizers

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, scikit-learn, hyperparameters

The basic equation of square exponential or RBF kernel is as follows:

[image]

Here l is the length scale and sigma is the variance parameter. The length scale controls how two points appear to be similar as it simply magnifies the distance between x and x'. The variance parameter controls how smooth the function is.

I want to optimize/train these parameters (l and sigma) with my training data sets. My training data sets are in the following form:

**X**: 2-D Cartesian coordinate as input data

**y**: radio signal strength (RSS) of Wi-Fi device at the 2-D coordinates points as observed output

According to [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor.html#sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor.get_params), the GaussianProcessRegressor class is defined as:

```
class sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=None, alpha=1e-10, optimizer=’fmin_l_bfgs_b’, n_restarts_optimizer=0, normalize_y=False, copy_X_train=True, random_state=None)
```

Here, the `optimizer` is a string or callable with L-BFGS-B algorithm as the default optimization algorithm (`“fmin_l_bfgs_b”`). The `optimizer` can either be one of the internally supported optimizers for optimizing the kernel’s parameters, specified by a string, or an externally defined optimizer passed as a callable. Furthermore, the only available internal optimizer in scikit-learn is `fmin_l_bfgs_b`.  However, I got to know that [scipy package](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) has many more optimizers. Since I wanted to use [trust-region-reflective algorithm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html#scipy.optimize.least_squares) to optimize the hyper-parameters, I tried to implement the algorithm as follows:

```
def fun_rosenbrock(Xvariable):
    return np.array([10*(Xvariable[1]-Xvariable[0]**2),(1-Xvariable[0])])
Xvariable = [1.0,1.0]
kernel = C(1.0, (1e-5, 1e5)) * RBF(1, (1e-1, 1e3))
trust_region_method = least_squares(fun_rosenbrock,[10,20,30,40,50],bounds=[0,100], method ='trf')

gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, optimizer = trust_region_method, alpha =1.2, n_restarts_optimizer=10)
gp.fit(X, y)
```

Since I couldn't figure out what actually the parameter 'fun' is in my case, I resorted to using rosenbrock function from [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html#scipy.optimize.least_squares) example (the example is at bottom of the page). I get the following error in console.

[image]

Is my approach of using **scipy package** to optimize the kernel parameters correct? How can I print the optimized value of the parameters? What is the parameter 'fun' in [scipy.optimize.least_squares](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html#scipy.optimize.least_squares) in my case?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three primary problems here:

1. The objective function that is being optimized is the rosenbrock function which is a test function for optimization purposes. It needs to be a cost function to be optimized based on the kernel parameters, internally for the GaussianProcessRegressor this is the log-marginal-likelihood and can be passed to the optimizer as a parameter.
2. The log-marginal-likelihood optimizer internally needs to be maximized. See section 1.7.1 [here.](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/gaussian_process.html#gaussian-process) Scipy least squares minimizes the objective function, so you will likely need to minimize the inverse of the objective function.
3. The formatting of the optimizer that is being passed into GaussianProcessRegressor, it needs to be passed in the format specified under the 'optimizer' parameter [in the docs.](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor.html#sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor)

As a partially working example,ignoring the kernel definition to emphasize the optimizer:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize,least_squares
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor

def trust_region_optimizer(obj_func, initial_theta, bounds):
    trust_region_method = least_squares(1/obj_func,initial_theta,bounds,method='trf')
    return (trust_region_method.x,trust_region_method.fun)

X=np.random.random((10,4))
y=np.random.random((10,1))
gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(optimizer = trust_region_optimizer, alpha =1.2, n_restarts_optimizer=10)
gp.fit(X, y)
```

The scipy optimizers return a results object, using the minimization of the rosenbrock test function as an example:

```
from scipy.optimize import least_squares,rosen
res=least_squares(rosen,np.array([0,0]),method='trf')
```

As shown above, the optimized values can be accessed using:

```
res.x
```

and the resulting value of the function to be minimized:

```
res.fun
```

which is what the 'fun' parameter represents. However now that the optimizer is working internally, you will need to access the resulting function value from scikit-learn:

```
gp.log_marginal_likelihood_value_
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. One more question (maybe dump Ques.), shouldn't any argument be passed while calling the trust_region_optimizer function inside the GaussianProcessRegressor object? Can I replace the obj_func with rosen while calling the trust_region_optimizer function? In my case the hyperparameter should be positive, so the bounds will be zero to some higher value.  I've presumed that the initial_theta is some initial hyperparameter guesses. Is there any limit on the size of it (size of initial_theta)?

Comment: Also, since the documentation says that the hyperparameters are optimized during fitting, I've presumed that the role of training data for optimizing the hyperparameter is done automatically, so we should not worried about it. Is my assumption correct?

Comment: @santobedi scikit-learn wants that particular format as it will pass the log-marginal-likelihood objective function as a parameter to the optimizer for the argument `obj_func`, you could check the source code to confirm. You can happily specify your own bounds in the function, I suspect you can do the same with the initial guess but scikit-learn will pass the kernel's initial parameters as an initial guess.

The training data are the X and y passed to the fit method.

Comment: I used the `trust_region_optimizer` as the optimizer in `GaussianProcessRegression`, and I get a TypeError as: 
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'function'`

Comment: If I copy and paste my code above it works, so I can't reproduce your error on my side. Try replacing `1/obj_func`  with `obj_func` to see if the problem lies there but that is not a solution.

Comment: While using `obj_func` , I get `ValueError:`jac` must be '2-point', '3-point', 'cs' or callable` . Using `1/obj_func` in `trust_region_optimizer` with or without the arguments yields  `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'function'`.  While using only your code, there is no error. However, while using your code with my training datatype, I get the error. I've used `kernel = C(1.0, (1e-5, 1e5)) * RBF(10.0)`. The training data are 2-D coordinates inputs and the observed value at those points. I need to predict the values at other 2-D coordinate points.

Comment: While using `'fmin_l_bfgs_b'` as the `optimizer` in the `GaussianProcessRegressor` object, it works fine. I'm facing the problem when I change the optimizer to `trust_region_optimizer`.

Comment: I checked your code with `x_test = np.random.random((10,4))`  to predict `y_pred = gp.predict(x_test)`. It works fine. However when I add `RBF` kernel in `GaussianProcessRegression`, I get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'function'`.