# TypeError while using scipy optimization algorithms with RBF kernel in GaussianProcessRegressor of Scikit-learn

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, scikit-learn, hyperparameters

I am trying to optimize the hyper-parameters using `trust_region_optimizer` from [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html#scipy.optimize.least_squares). The log-marginal-likelihood optimizer internally needs to be maximized in my case. Scipy least squares minimize the objective function, so I need to minimize the inverse of the objective function. Following is my code:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize,least_squares
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF, ConstantKernel as C
from scipy.optimize import least_squares,rosen

def trust_region_optimizer(obj_func, initial_theta, bounds):
    trust_region_method = least_squares(1/obj_func,initial_theta,bounds,method='trf')
    return (trust_region_method.x,trust_region_method.fun)

X=np.random.random((10,4))
y=np.random.random((10,1))
kernel = C(1.0, (1e-5, 1e5)) * RBF(10.0)
gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, optimizer = trust_region_optimizer(rosen,[10,20,30,40], [0,100]), alpha =1.2, n_restarts_optimizer=10)
gp.fit(X, y)
```

While running the above code, I get the following error on console:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'function'
```

However, If I remove the `kernel`, there is no error at all.

I tried to replace `1/obj_func` with `obj_func`, I get the following error:

```
ValueError:jac` must be '2-point', '3-point', 'cs' or callable`
```

However, I cannot replace `1/obj_func` with `obj_func` in my work.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I noticed you are in the habit of pasting Python code as html or js snippets. Please do not do that because the browser cannot run the Python code anyway, and there is no syntax highlighting. See my edit how to correctly format Python code.

Comment: What does `1/obj_func` mean? Inverse of the function or the reciprocal of the returned values from `obj_func`?

Comment: @VivekKumar Its inverse of the function.

Comment: Please explain in more detail (preferable edit your question), what 1/obj_func should do?

Comment: @VivekKumar I had asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50265501/optimize-the-kernel-parameters-of-rbf-kernel-for-gpr-in-scikit-learn-using-inter/50327824?noredirect=1#comment87702787_50327824) question, however, the answer do not solve my problem (though it helped me to understand). `obj_func` is explained there. If you want, I can rewrite in this question too.

Comment: Well first is to remove the `(rosen,[10,20,30,40], [0,100])` part from `GaussianProcessRegressor(...)`. The obj_func will be supplied by the GPR.

Comment: @VivekKumar I did. I used  gp =  `GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, optimizer= trust_region_optimizer, alpha =1.2, n_restarts_optimizer=10) ` and still get  `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'function' `. :(